# Pay Early Feature Difficult to Locate

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to pay my bills early as I am really worried about disconnecting service due to delayed payments

I made three payments previously using a feature called pay early. I located that Pay Early Link with great difficulty. This time I can not locate it. I was struggling for hours to locate the feature.

I searched google, but no one gives any detail.

Please help.

Comment: The automatic payments can eliminate `disconnecting service due to delayed payments` worries. Granted, I also understand reluctance to enable such payments, which in some cases can bring bigger worries.

Comment: I have only one debit card. I have to deposit money in advance for the card before it can be used for a payment.

Comment: Ah, right. Forgot about that aspect. Never mind, please.

Answer (score 0):

Select Billing.
Then Select Overview.
Select Payment Overview Tab.
You will find the pay early button.

[image: Screen Shot]